# how to read remote xml file in classic asp and insert that data into db

Tags: xml, asp-classic

```
<%
Set objSrvHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.4.0")
objSrvHTTP.open "GET", "http://something.com/rss.xml", false

objSrvHTTP.send()
Feed = objSrvHTTP.ResponseText 
response.write("=" & Feed)

%>
```

output we are getting like below on our classic asp page, that is all raw data,
but it is difficult to separate and insert such data into database..

output.asp file shows:
http://something.com/rss.xmlhttp://something.com/rss.xml15http://something.com/images/artwork/something.comL_sml.jpghttp://something.com/AED/Default.aspxhttp://something.com/AED/ARS.aspx37be012b-06f2-4f88-9768-a432e5c8a240Sat, 22 Oct 2011 07:37:56 GMT1 United Arab Emirates Dirham = 1.15256 Argentine PesoSouth Americahttp://something.com/AED/AUD.aspxf26fa2db-960b-457c-89d2-e9c3b6c16baeSat, 22 Oct 2011 07:37:56 GMT1 United Arab Emirates Dirham = 0.26247 Australian DollarOceaniahttp://something.com/AED/BBD.aspxc2a3faff-9c09-4cf6-be98-b6a625f7d971Sat, 22 Oct 2011 07:37:56 GMT1 United Arab Emirates Dirham = 0.54459 Barbadian DollarNort

Answer (score 0):

Use the [responseXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property, not `responseText`.